# Loop not counting

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to get the following code to add how many people can retire and not. the code displays but does not add. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$canRetire= 0;
$notRetired = 0;

$agesFile = fopen("ages.txt", "r");
$nextAge = fgets($agesFile);
while (feof($agesFile) ){
   list($agesFile)=explode(":",$nextAge);
   if ($agesFile > 65){ 
       $canRetired = $canRetired + 1;
   }
   else{
       $notretired = $notRetired + 1;
   }
   $nextAge = fgets($agesFile);
}
fclose ($agesFile);

print("<p>Number of people can retired : $canRetired</p>");
print("<p>Number of people not retired: $notRetired</p>");
?>
```

Comment: **$notretired = $notRetired + 1;** Notice the "R" vs "r" in variable names

Comment: A quicker way to add +1 to variables, is simply doing `$canRetired++;`

Comment: Also, you probably meant `while (!feof(`

Comment: `while (feof($agesFile) ){` - did you mean `while(!feof($agesFile))`? You want to stop when you reach the end of file, not when you leave it.

Comment: I think this question isn't a good format for SO because it's comprised of typographical errors, and a very simple mistake.

Comment: @bengoesboom good catch. Time to close this as a typo question.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `while(!feof(...))`?

You want to stop when you reach the end of file.

Plus it looks like you've got some spelling errors:

```
$notretired = $notRetired + 1;
```

Notice how the R is lower case on the left and upper case on the right.

Also at the beginning you have `$canRetire` and in the if condition inside the loop you have `$canRetired`.

And just another little hint for you: `$notRetired = $notRetired + 1;` is the same as `$notRetired++;`

Comment: @crush have you noticed anything else?

Comment: @JanDvorak Well, now it's full solution. He originally only mentioned the while loop.

Comment: There is a typo at the beginning of the file too: `$canRetire= 0;` but that shouldn't affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

Made a couple modifications to cases, and what appears to be a type based on the variables you have defined. Looks like the variable $canRetire does not match $canretired.

Using `while(feof($fh))` is basically saying, do this for the EOF. Which renders that entire loop useless. Using `while(!feof($fh))` will allow you to loop until the EOF.

```
<?php
$canRetired= 0;
$notRetired = 0;

$agesFile = fopen("ages.txt", "r");
$nextAge = fgets($agesFile);
while (!feof($agesFile) ){
   list($agesFile)=explode(":",$nextAge);
   if ($agesFile > 65){ 
       $canRetired = $canRetired++;
   }
   else{
       $notRetired = $notRetired++;
   }
   $nextAge = fgets($agesFile);
}
fclose ($agesFile);

print("<p>Number of people can retired : $canRetired</p>");
print("<p>Number of people not retired: $notRetired</p>");
?>
```